# Layout issue in different device in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas, android-framelayout

I have Imageview inside a framelayout. I have set scaletype for imageview as MATRIX, but it's looks different in different devices.

Here is layout I used:

[image: Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime]

[image: Asus zenfone 2]

```
 <FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/canvasView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"

android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_baseview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:scaleType="matrix" />

<Utils.DrawingHelper
android:id="@+id/drawing"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#00000000"

/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In my Java file I am displaying image

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
actualImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(Datas.received_uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
ImageViewHeight = options.outHeight;
ImageViewWidth = options.outWidth;

img_baseview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

canvasView.getLayoutParams().height = ImageViewHeight;
canvasView.getLayoutParams().width = ImageViewWidth;
canvasView.requestLayout();

Log.e("ESize", ImageViewWidth + "---" + ImageViewHeight);
Log.e("ESize", canvasView.getHeight() + "---" + canvasView.getWidth());

try {
actualImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Datas.received_uri);
bitmapMaster = actualImageBitmap;
effect_bitmap = bitmapMaster;
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
// img_baseview.setImageURI(Datas.received_uri);
img_baseview.setImageBitmap(actualImageBitmap);
```

Comment: just set  android:scaleType="fitXY" and mange imageview width and height using @dimen in different values folder

Comment: @Radhey we don't want to set ScaleType="fitXY" and image height and width can not be define in dimen as its pick up from gallary camera

Comment: then what you try to do !? pick image from gallery and set it in image view . thats it ??

Comment: @Radhey fitXY streach image its not displaying properly

Comment: yes but image size is 1200 X 786

Comment: just want to display image as it's size in any devices

Comment: not possible ! android:layout_centerVertical="true" why it is here ?.and just replace matrix with fitXY ,let me know what happen with the help of screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128252/discussion-between-pcpriyanka-and-radhey).

Comment: @Radhey can you please reply in chat

Comment: Since you're a 2K user, a quick reminder: we prefer questions without voting advice (e.g. asking people not to downvote, or to upvote) and we would rather posters did not add "please help" begging to everything they post. You're on a help site, we know you need help! `:-)`

Comment: @halfer Thanks for your advice. But I'm a iOS developer so now learning Android. When I add this question some one downvote within 1 min. That's why added it later.

Comment: You have 2K, so you can survive the odd downvote - trying to control peoples' voting behaviour is like ordering the sun to come out. Most Stack Overflow users do not log in or vote, and for them voting commentary is just filler material to be skipped over. Put it in the comments if you really must, but I don't think it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

use [CENTER_INSIDE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: android:scaleType="centerInside".

instead of `MATRIX`
remve `img_baseview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);`

Check out

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/canvasView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Utils.DrawingHelper
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_baseview" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_baseview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: using CENTER_INSIDE its working but I want framelayout size as image displaying in imageview

Comment: u want <Utils.DrawingHelper to cme up

Comment: see in framelayout I have used imageview and drawingview now image size is 1200 X 786 so My drawingview size must be 1200 X 786. image size is large so display using matrix but it is not displying same in all devicess

Comment: make

 <FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/canvasView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: u can make wrap_content in FrameLayout, DrawingHelper or align DrawingHelper alignend="IMAGE" and alignstar="IMAGE"